# animate.css does not work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Firefox 29.0 and I am currently working on my website. I am using the bootstrap 3 framework and I am trying to get different effects on various elements using animate.css and wow.js. Now I am new to anything outside html and css but I must have enbedded and used it right to some extend as the effects show in Chrome and Safari but nothing at all happens in Firefox. Any suggestions?

Comment: check for firefox compatible code

Answer (score 0):

[Current Firefox implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) fail unless time values have units. Use 0s or 0ms insetad of just 0 (or whatever time value you are using).

Example: [This doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/E2UhJ/1/) in Firefox, but if you change to `-moz-animation: rotate 20s linear 0s infinite;` it will work.